# Insertar Registros en tablas Sql Server a travez de parametros en el nombre de la tabla @UserName

Tags: sql

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con mi problema, se los voy agradecer.
Necesito crear un procedimiento almacenado en SQL, donde a través de parámetros envíe el `@NombredelaTabla` y `@todoslosparametros_a_insertar`, ejemplo tengo el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Podrías compartir el SQL copiando y pegando y no como captura de pantalla?

Comment: la verdad es que a menos que todas las tablas tengan exactamente las mismas columnas, tu solicitud no hace mucho sentido

Comment: No se puede proporcionar el nombre de una tabla como dato `varchar(50)`, por lo que tu consulta SQL fallará. Lo que necesitas es realizar una consulta preparada, en la que agregas el nombre de la tabla a la cadena que contiene el SQL. Como esto puede llevar a ataques de inyección SQL es muy importante que previamente hagas las comprobaciones necesarias para que no se pueda ejecutar esa consulta sin filtrar adecuadamente el contenido de `@UserName`. En tu ejemplo estás definiendo un valor estático, pero si ese valor va a ser dinámico podrías sufrir ese problema.